# How to import gradle project into STS 3.7.2

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, spring-tool-suite

i download fresh STS, do 'import' and... there is nothing related to gradle.

do i have to install some plugins first? or maybe preferred way is to add `apply plugin 'eclipse'` and run `gradle eclipse` first? what is the suggested way?

Answer (score 7):

There are three options to import Gradle projects into STS/Eclipse:

- install the Gradle Integration for Eclipse via the STS dashboard or the Eclipse marketplace and use that. This fits into the STS picture and integrates with its components.
- install the Buildship project, this is the "official" Gradle integration for Eclipse from Eclipse and this should be the extension of your choice looking forward.
- use Gradle to create Eclipse-specific project metadata and import the project as existing Eclipse project.

Comment: they are all more-less equal or some of them provides better experience/integration? or is more preferred/suggested solution

Comment: if you work a lot with Spring projects and heavily use the STS features, I would prefer the Gradle Integration for Eclipse via the STS dashboard for the moment. In general, I would prefer the Buildship integration, since that is the one that is worked on heavily by the guys from Gradle themselves. In the end I would give them a try to see what works in your environment the best.

Answer (score 3):

From https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/wiki/Migration-guide-from-STS-Gradle-to-Buildship

> There are two major Gradle plugins for Eclipse: one created by **SpringSource** as part of the **Spring Tool Suite** and one called **Buildship** developed by **Gradle Inc**. Since **Buildship** became an **eclipse.org project**, the SpringSource developers are planning to phase out their tooling and switch to **Buildship**.

So **Buildship** is the only currently supported variant.